# ElasticSearch QueryParsingException failed to find geo_point field

Tags: elasticsearch, geospatial

Trying to build search as follows:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "50km",
          "coordinates": {
            "lat": 52.5234051,
            "lon": 4.113999
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where *coordinates* is of type *'geo_point'*.

But when I try to run this query, the elasticsearch.log pops up with an error: 
[locations] failed to find geo_point field [coordinates]

**Edit:**

This is part of the /locations/location/_mapping:

```
{
  "locations": {
  "mappings": {
  "location": {
  "properties": {
    ...
    "coordinates": {
      "properties": {
        "lat": {
          "type": "string"
         },
        "lon": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
   ...
 }
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: What us the field name of geo point??

Comment: @BlackPOP: see edit of original post

Comment: I think you didint use geo_point in mapping.. refer this http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-point-type.html

Comment: @BlackPOP You are right. I accidentally wrote the mapping but didn't apply it. Works now. Thx.

Comment: I have same problem when I check  the mapping field in Management > index pattern , the mapping is geo_point and it is correct but when I write query _GET theIndex/_mapping/_ in dev tools is 
`"location": { "properties": { "lat": { "type": "float"  }, "lon": { "type": "float" } } },`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is mapping.you need to use geo_point in mapping.. [refer this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-geo-point-type.html) .

Comment: Edited with latest link..!

Comment: I have the same problem, can you explain more ?